# Middleware parameters and packages

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

I have a route defined as

```
Route::get('/test', 'Package\Namespace\Controllers\TestController@index')
    ->name('index-test')
    ->middleware(['Package\Namespace\Middleware\TestMiddleware']);
```

I want to call another middleware keeping the syntax (`->middleware(...)`). I have looked [at the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/middleware#middleware-parameters) but I cannot figure out how to do this using the above syntax and namespaced middleware (I am developing a package)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its just array:

```
Route::get('/test', 'Package\Namespace\Controllers\TestController@index')
    ->name('index-test')
    ->middleware(['Package\Namespace\Middleware\TestMiddleware','Package\Namespace\Middleware\TestMiddleware2','Package\Namespace\Middleware\TestMiddleware3']);
```

> to [pass parameters to middleware](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/middleware#middleware-parameters): Middleware parameters may be
>   specified when defining the route by separating the middleware name
>   and parameters with a :. Multiple parameters should be delimited by
>   commas:

```
Route::get('/test', 'Package\Namespace\Controllers\TestController@index')
    ->name('index-test')
    ->middleware(['Package\Namespace\Middleware\TestMiddleware:parameter','Package\Namespace\Middleware\TestMiddleware2:parameter','Package\Namespace\Middleware\TestMiddleware3:parameter']);
```

Comment: Is this assigning multiple middlewares to a route or passing parameters to the middleware? I want the latter